# Black Screen After Sleep (Win 8)

Tags: windows-8, sleep

I have an SSD only, Intel HD Graphics only, Ultrabook running on Windows 8 64-bit and after I turn it back on, after a long sleep of a few hours, the screen remains black even though the power is on (the fan and keyboard backlight are on). I have to force a shut down and switch it back on to use it normally again.

Hibernation and hybrid-sleep are turned off. It comes out of sleep of less than an hour just fine. Any advise?

Mark

Comment: Please take a look if it is your case https://superuser.com/questions/1612933/black-screen-after-sleep-mode-or-screen-off-in-windows10/1612934#1612934

Answer (score 1):

Check those 2 KB articles from MS:

**Windows 8 restarts to a blank screen after a standard shutdown or hibernation**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2756559/en-us

**Windows 8 hangs on black screen after resume from hybrid sleep**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2849217/en-us

Comment: Thank you. I had updated Windows fully, including the updates mentioned in the articles, but the screen still goes black after a long sleep.

This article, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2850674 , mentions losing power during sleep, but the laptop was plugged in the whole time and with a full battery.

Comment: does hibernation work?

Comment: I just tried it, and it works. I will try it again tonight and leave it on a long hibernation over night, just to make sure.

Comment: if hibernation works, use hibernation instead of sleep.

Comment: But I only have a solid state drive and hibernation is not ideal for the longevity of a solid state drive.

Comment: todays SSD can handle those write operations fine. I also have a SSD and use hibernation all the time.

Comment: FYI, if I hibernate from the start menu it doesn't have a problem, but if I hibernate from closing the lid, it still has the issue of the black screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known Windows 8 & Windows 8.1 issue. It's related to Display Adapter & Monitor Drivers.

You have to boot your PC into safe mode to disable Display Adapter & Monitor Drivers.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution for this issue; i press/hold "**Windows**"+"**P**"+"**P**"

Hold "windows" button and press "P" twice,

once you get your screen back on, 
Hold both : "**windows**" + "**Shift**" buttons and press "**P**" **twice**, to get back your initial resolution.

this combination changes the video output to another video device(ex: video projector),
but since there is no other video device connected to your computer, it changes the resolution of the video output,
therefore the default video device(your video card) get the video signal and switch on.

No need to reboot anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the HD's disks didn't start rotating on time. It happens after long hours of sleep.

Comment: But I only have a solid state drive. Does a solid state drive have an equivalent problem?

Comment: Incorrect. Mine happens immediately after I put it to sleep.