# Black screen after Sleep mode or screen off in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, hibernate

I have a N552vw ASUS Windows 10 Home.

After some year of use, I get this problem.
Sometimes, as the PC is commanded to go to sleep or hibernate mode (by user command or by power option timer), or as it is "waking up" from sleep mode, the screen does not tunr on anymore.

I tryed to "wake it up" by moving the mouse or pressing some keywords, but I get no response, so every timeI get this problem I have to shut the PC down by holding down the power button.

Specifically, when trying to wake up the PC after sleep/hibernate mode, it is like it is actually waking up (because I hear the fan reactivating and other usual noises the PC des as it reactivates), but it seems that the only thing not working is the screen turning on.

Furthermore, as I already mentioned, the problem does not occur only after sleep/hibernate mode, but also when the PC "is trying to go to sleep/hibernate mode".

This also made me to switch the Windows sleep mode settings to `"turn off the screen after: never"` and `"sleep mode after: never"`.

I also have reset my PC to factory data by using [Windows 10 reset guided procedure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-refresh-reset-or-restore-your-pc-51391d9a-eb0a-84a7-69e4-c2c1fbceb8dd), but the problem still remains.

I noticed the problem was also reported on Microsoft community with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60939551/black-screen-in-chrome-after-sleep). However, it did not get a unique answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though this did not solve my proble, I have read that one possible solution is following the `Step 3` and `step 5` instructions in [this article](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/computer-wont-wake-up-from-sleep-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Sometimes%20your%20computer%20will%20not,the%20box%20and%20press%20Enter):
disabling the **fast startup** and **hybrid sleep** and enabling **wake timers**.

### Disabling the fast startup

On your keyboard, press the Windows `logo key` and `R` at the same time, then copy & paste `powercfg.cpl` into the box and click `OK`.

A new window opens, on its left bar, click `Choose what the power buttons do`.

A new window opens, on its top, click `Change settings that are currently unavailable` writing with the admin logo.

Then uncheck the box `Turn on fast startup (Recommended)`, then click `Save changes` and close the window.

### Disabling Hybrid sleep and enabling Wake timers

On your keyboard, press the Windows `logo key` and `R` at the same time, then type `powercfg.cpl` into the box and press OK.

A new window opens, click the chosen power plan and click `Change plan settings`

A new window opens, click `Change advanced power settings`.

A new window opens, in the list, expand `Sleep`, then

- set `Allow hybrid sleep` in `Off`
- set `Allow wake timers` to `Enable`, then click `Apply` and then
  `ok`.

[image]

At the end **restart your computer**.